# Unable to PUT file from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm making a form that's supposed to upload a file to a `PUT` endpoint. I'm able to upload this file as part of a model instance (`tab_community`) but I'm getting a 400 error. My idea was to use the model controller's `PUT` endpoint to upload the file into Rails (since the file upload/import is another way to update `tab_community` entries), but this might be generating the 400 error since the file is not part of the `tab_community` model.

If my guess is correct, how do you handle properties and values that are not part of the original model? Is there some way to tell the endpoint to not update the database as it normally would if there is a file in the request? And if my guess is wrong and it's something else... What did I do wrong?

I'm including everything for completeness...

Client code:

```
function import_community(form_data) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // using 3rd party module
    // https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload
    Upload.upload({
        url: __env.api_url + ':' + __env.port + '/tab_communities/' + form_data.id + '.json'
        , data: form_data
        , method: 'PUT'
    })
        .then(
            function(response) {
                deferred.resolve(response.data.response);
            }
            , function(data, status, headers, config) {
                deferred.resolve(JSON.parse('{"response": {"method": "PUT", "result": "error", "status": "' + status + '"}}'));
            }
        );
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Server code:

```
  # PATCH/PUT /tab_communities/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tab_communities/1.json
  def update
    if @tab_community.update(tab_community_params)
      render :show, status: :ok, location: @tab_community
    else
      render json: @tab_community.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Error output:

```
Started PUT "/tab_communities/33.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-18 16:48:28 -0400
Processing by TabCommunitiesController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"33", "name"=>"test_aug_190000", "ref_community_type_id"=>"7", "created_at"=>"2017-08-17T01:56:28.651Z", "updated_at"=>"2017-08-18T19:54:10.494Z", "url"=>"http://localhost:3000/tab_communities/33", "$$hashKey"=>"object:58", "import"=>{"this_file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000a527c90 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/joe_t/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20170818-20396-pmgjwr.csv>, @original_filename="TechVCMembers.csv", @content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"import[this_file]\"; filename=\"TechVCMembers.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel\r\n">}}
  TabClientSeat Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "tab_client_seats".* FROM "tab_client_seats" WHERE "tab_client_seats"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TabCommunity Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "tab_communities".* FROM "tab_communities" WHERE "tab_communities"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 33], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 49ms (ActiveRecord: 5.9ms)



ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: tab_community):

app/controllers/tab_communities_controller.rb:57:in `tab_community_params'
app/controllers/tab_communities_controller.rb:34:in `update'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: tab_community):
```

what does your `tab_community_params` method look like?  In the error output it looks like the file field that you're trying to upload is named `import`, is that missing from `tab_community_params`?

Comment: In the parameters list above the `import` field is listed as: `"import"=>{"this_file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000a527c90 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/joe_t/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20170818-20396-pmgjwr.csv>, @original_filename="TechVCMembers.csv", @content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"import[this_file]\"; filename=\"TechVCMembers.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel\r\n">}`